# Gridbox CSS: Responsiveness / Float Main Section Left on XS

Tags: css

I made an example in codepen:
Link: https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/gGVPrm

How do I get section B to float left on XS/mobile phone (sections A, C, D will hide). Getting all sections to "stack float left" would also work.

The problem seems to be that section A, C, & D are still "there" but hidden causing section B to "float right".

```
<div class="container-fluid wrapper">
<div class="box a hidden-sm hidden-xs"> <b><u>Definitions <br></b></u>
Grid-gap: provides an easy way for spacing our content <br>
Grid: generates a block-level grid <br>
  Inline-grid: generates an inline-level grid<br>
  Subgrid: Indicate that you want the sizes of its rows/columns to be taken from its parent rather than specifying its own.
  </div>

  <div class="box b">
    <b><u>Conclusion <br></b></u>
    Flexbox and Gridbox can be used together (with bootrap). <br>
    Flexbox is best for single rows while Grixbox is best for "2 dimensions" <br>
    Non-flexible measurements such as px can make boxes not appear on screen if the screen width is less than the px size. <br>

    <br><b>Sources</b><br><a href="https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/">https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/<br></a>
    <a href="https://gridbyexample.com/examples/">https://gridbyexample.com/examples/<br></a>
    <a href="https://css-tricks.com/things-ive-learned-css-grid-layout/">https://css-tricks.com/things-ive-learned-css-grid-layout/<br></a>
     <a href="https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/">https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/<br></a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp">https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp<br></a>
   </div>

  <div class="box c hidden-sm hidden-xs"><b><u>What is flexbox? </b></u><br> 
Flexbox is for one dimensional layout (row or column). 
<br>"Flexbox is a single dimension – in a row OR a column." -Rachel Andrews <br>
       Warning: Flexbox is NOT compatible with some IE verisions.
  </div>

  <div class="box d hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <b><u>What is gridbox? <br></b></u>
      Grid is designed to be used with flexbox, not instead of it.  CSS grid is for two dimensional layout. <br>"Grid is for layout of items in two dimensions – rows AND columns" - Rachel Andrews.
  </div>
</div>
```

If you -1 please explain why for better posting in future as I am new to forms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using flex. Check the code below.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .left{
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .right {
  order: 1;
  }
  
  .container > div {
  flex: 1;
  }
  
  .container img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block
  }
  
  .innerBottom {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column
  }
  
  
  @media(min-width: 768px){
    .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    .innerBottom {
      flex-direction: row
    }
    
    
  .left{
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .right {
  order: 2;
  }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">


  
  <div class="right">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x200/cccccc?text=Right">
  </div>
  
  <div class="left">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1200x200/cc0000?text=Left">
    </div>
    
    <div class="innerBottom">
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x200/azazaz?text=LeftBottomLeft">
      </div>
    
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x200/ddd?text=LeftBottomRight">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Even better than expected as it lays them stacked. Marked it as answer. Thanks!